# How to map a DataFrame to another based on a column that starts with strings contained in the first DataFrame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have two DataFrames and I want to map information from one to the other.

First DataFrame:

```
    A         B    
0   pokaichi  56156 
1   klavatur  45156  
2   monopol   32154 
3   berate    98741
```

Second DataFrame:

```
    C   D      E
0   be  18485  Bond
1   mo  14285  Roger
2   kl  74853  Mika
3   po  85655  Loki
```

How can I map the `E` column from the second DataFrame to the first DataFrame, so that the new column from the first DataFrame is a result of the string in the `A` column that **starts with** the string in `C` column?

So the first DataFrame should look like this after applying the mapping:

```
    A         B      E
0   pokaichi  56156  Loki
1   klavatur  45156  Mika
2   monopol   32154  Roger
3   berate    98741  Bond
```

I tried using [`str.startswith`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html) with [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html), but to no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [31]: df1
Out[31]:
          A      B
0  pokaichi  56156
1  klavatur  45156
2   monopol  32154
3    berate   9741

In [32]: df2
Out[32]:
    C      D      E
0  be  18485   Bond
1  mo  14285  Roger
2  kl  74853   Mika
3  po  85655   Loki

In [33]: df1['C'] = df1['A'].str[:2].map(df2.set_index('C')['E'])

In [34]: df1
Out[34]:
          A      B      C
0  pokaichi  56156   Loki
1  klavatur  45156   Mika
2   monopol  32154  Roger
3    berate   9741   Bond
```

Alternatively, you could do a merge if you are okay with creating a new dataframe.

```
In [43]: df1.merge(df2[['C', 'E']], left_on=df1['A'].str[:2], right_on='C').drop('C', axis=1)
Out[43]:
          A      B      E
0  pokaichi  56156   Loki
1  klavatur  45156   Mika
2   monopol  32154  Roger
3    berate   9741   Bond
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below steps:

```
pat=r'({})'.format('|'.join(df2.C))
#'(be|mo|kl|po)'
d=df2.set_index('C')['E'] #creating a series with C as Index and E as values
```

---

Then we use: [`series.str.extract()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) to extract `df2.C` from `df1.A` and using [`series.map()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) we map the values to generate the expected output.

```
df1['E']=df1.A.str.extract(pat,expand=False).map(d)
print(df1)
```

---

```
          A      B      E
0  pokaichi  56156   Loki
1  klavatur  45156   Mika
2   monopol  32154  Roger
3    berate  98741   Bond
```